# Will my websocket server affect nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, server

I have the following two server files.

1. `server1.js`
2. `server2.js`

In the `server1.js`, I have a websocket server running on port 3500 using `ws`[1] npm package.
In the `server2.js`, I have a `nodejs server` running on port 80. They are both running on the same Microsoft Windows Server 2016 with Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @2.40 GHz and 14 GB RAM.

My question is if there are 10k simultaneous websocket client connection connecting to `server1.js` websocket server, would this affect the performance of the `node.js server` running on `server2.js`?

1. https://github.com/websockets/ws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short yes, if `server1` has a big load this will affect the performance of the whole machine and the bandwidth. So it will affect the performance of the other server indirectly by draining resources of the host machine. How much it will be affected depends on how much the connections stress the server. You could limit the resources available to the `server1` so it cannot consume as many resources as it wants.

Comment: If so, let's say, the resource is 100%. If ```server1``` always stays under resource usage of 30% and ```server2``` is also under 30%, the websocket server will not interfere with how many clients can make request to nodejs server, right?

Comment: The number of clients that can make requests will not be affected in any case. What can be affected is how long it will take for the request to reach the server and the response to go back to the client, and this will be affected by the network/bandwidth usage. Think of it as your home connection when you download/upload something. Now with the resource usage of the server itself, it is not so easy to say if one application will impact the performance of the other.